# What is the biblical basis for "March for Jesus" or "Jesus Day"?

Tags: biblical-basis, religious-practice, civil-government, church-local, feasts

As a Christian, I believe that the scripture contains the basis for all the activity that I, as a member of the Church, need to get involved.

Of course, we can't find all kind of Christian activity on the text in *stricto sensu*, but we surely need to find a consistent theological ground that clearly support every activity that we get involved into.

That being said, my question is: **what is the biblical basis for things like "March for Jesus" or "Jesus Day"**? There is any commitment for the church to march into the streets or to make a spiritual parade, like romans had the [Lupercalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupercalia) and feasts like that?

I can't remember any verse in the NT that supports [such a behavior](https://www.flickr.com/photos/portaligospel/sets/72157654660414138/).

Some points:

- The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_for_Jesus) provides no such thing as a Bible basis, even in the "further reading section".
- No event website provides any Biblical basis at all, like [London Jesus Day](http://londonjesusday.com/) or [Brazilian March for Jesus](http://www.marchaparajesus.com.br/) or even [this really old website, from the beginnings](http://www.ad2000.org/re71231.htm).
- Here in Brazil, we have the biggest March for Jesus and is important to state that the Pentecostal movement is largely involved with that.

Comment: To satisfy my curiosity, what is your 'consistent theological ground to clearly support' posting questions on an internet site?

Comment: You misunderstood the point. *"we can't find all kind of christian activity on the text in stricto sensu"*. "posting questions on an internet site" is the strict act. But you clearly have a vast theological basis for "reprove, rebuke, exhort" and so on, like you read at 2 Tm 4:2. Asking for a bible basis is a kind of exhortation. Now, if you do this offline or online doens't make any difference, only if you want to be "picky", instead of dealing with the real issue of the question.

Comment: Since that's the level of 'theological support' you are asking about there is clearly theological support for "praising God", especially with singing and music, and also for "making God's name known", both of which are the aims of March for Jesus . Is that going to be enough for you?

Comment: Not at all. But here is is: you can go and create a question at SE about the thological basis for using SE, and i'll be glad to try providing you an argument there (as strong as i can), as an answer to your doubt. But now you are on my question about March for Jesus, and, if THIS is your theological basis for March for Jesus, i recomend you post this as an answer, but i can assure you: this is really weak.

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions), which explains why we are not looking to  give you an explanation that satisfies you personally. We will be happy to explain the reasons behind March for Jesus, but if you don't happen to like them there is nothing we can do about that.

Comment: I'm not asking you to satisfy me at all, if so, please, quote it so i can apologize. Stating that someone have a poor theological background is stating the obvious when the argument is circular (a because b). "We will be happy to explain the reasons behind March for Jesus" - That is just what i asked for: a good, biblical and coherent reason behind March for Jesus. Read my question again and you'll see. Not hard at all. (:

Comment: PS.: And it seems that YOU or someone else have disliked my  question for personal taste, because there is nothing technically wrong with it. If so, be welcome to edit it and fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be no records of the specific theological basis on which March for Jesus was founded. However based on its priorities and aims it is easy enough to discern general theological principles for the event.

The founders (like many Christians) are coming from a theological traditional where it is not necessary to find specific biblical approval for something as long as it is in accordance with Biblical principles. The general purposes of March for Jesus are well supported in scripture:

- **Praising God**. The main focus of March for Jesus is praise for God. Plenty of scripture attests to the need for this, both in public and private.
- **Making the name of Jesus known** Obviously also commanded as a central part of Christianity.
- **Prayer** Prayer is also a major focus of March for Jesus, specifically prayer for the city the march takes place in. Christians are commanded to pray not just for themselves but for their rulers and cities they live in.

Since there is a 'vast theological basis' for these activities, the founders take the view that there is nothing wrong, and much that is right, with adapting them to a present-day form.